# android market://details?id= not working for app

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-intent

The Android `market://details?id=<pname>` link is not working for only one of my apps and it is driving me insane.  I am pulling my hair out does anyone have any idea?  It is my "Wrap It Up Box" link that just comes up as `"Not Found" "The requested item could not be found."` (last link below).  If you search Wrap It Up Box it shows up just fine, just directly linking to it isn't working.

```
public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.morebubrubsoundboardBtn:
            Intent goToMarket = null;
            goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.bubrubsoundboard"));
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        break;
        case R.id.morefarmvillehelperBtn:
            Intent goToMarket1 = null;
            goToMarket1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.farmvillehelper"));
            startActivity(goToMarket1);
        break;
        case R.id.morefarmvillehelperfreeBtn:
            Intent goToMarket2 = null;
            goToMarket2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.farmvillehelperfree"));
            startActivity(goToMarket2);
        break;
        case R.id.morefishvillehelperBtn:
            Intent goToMarket3 = null;
            goToMarket3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.fishvillehelper"));
            startActivity(goToMarket3);
        break;
        case R.id.morefishvillehelperfreeBtn:
            Intent goToMarket4 = null;
            goToMarket4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.fishvillehelperfree"));
            startActivity(goToMarket4);
        break;
        case R.id.morelarrysoundboardBtn:
            Intent goToMarket5 = null;
            goToMarket5 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.larrysoundboard"));
            startActivity(goToMarket5);
        break;
        case R.id.moreleonsoundboardBtn:
            Intent goToMarket6 = null;
            goToMarket6 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.leonsoundboard"));
            startActivity(goToMarket6);
        break;
        case R.id.morewrapitupboxBtn:
            Intent goToMarket7 = null;
            goToMarket7 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.jayavon.wrapitupbox"));
            startActivity(goToMarket7);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry for you, but you have a typing error in your package name of "Wrap It Up Box". You think it's `com.jayavon.wrapitupbox` but it's actually `com.javavon.wrapitupbox` with **javavon** instead of **jayavon**.

Comment: OMG, I want to punch myself.  Thank you so much for catching that.  How can I change it in all locations in eclipse?  I assume there must be some spot to do that?

Comment: I think I have found all of the necessary spots required to fix my package name.  Thank you so much I really appreciate your help!

Comment: could also use a constant string for the constant parts. ;o)

Comment: If you hit control f in eclipse you can use the find and replace to change all the mistakes quickly

Comment: Using alt+shift+r (Refractor, also available by right clicking) on a variable, you can rename entire file.

Answer (score 3):

Some phones don't have Google Store. You should use "https://" in this case:

```
private String getGooglePlayStoreUrl(){
    String id = activity.getApplicationInfo().packageName; // current google play is   using package name as id

    PackageManager packageManager = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + id);
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(marketUri);
    if (marketIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
      return "market://details?id=" + id;
    else
      return "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + id;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use market link like this :

```
market://details?id=com.nuazure.bookbuffet
```

Comment: Do you think you could explain this, and what makes it an answer to the question asked?

Comment: Not answering the question